# как окончательно убить зомби процессы в Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, процесс, multiprocessing

Проблема следующая: есть два потока один создает (создатель) задачи (процессы), второй их при определенных условиях должен убивать (киллер).
Для передачи информации используется общий словарь dict() в которой создатель пишет процессы, а киллер запускает для заданного `dict["PROC_TO_KILL"].terminate`

Вопрос следующий, при вызове этой функции `terminate` процессы продолжают отображаться "зомби процессы Z", как окончательно убить процесс?
И подвопрос: как сделать рекурсивное удаление всех процессов которые были порождены этим процессом (или это будет сделано автоматически)?
!Нюанс: в режиме отладки код работает нормально, процесс убиваются без появления "зомбарей".

Свои варианты закомментированы в коде киллера, они либо не работают либо дают тот же вариант.

**Main**

```
def Main():
    table_proc = dict()  # таблица процессов 
    lock = Lock()   

    # создание классов-потоков
    creator = Creator(... lock, table_proc)
    creator.start()  # запуск создателя

    killer = Killer(...lock, table_proc)
    killer.start()  # запуск киллера

    creator.join()  # main() ждет смерти этого потока
    killer.join()  # main() ждет смерти и этого потока


# Тестовая функция процесс порождаемый создателем
def New_Func(name):
    while True:
        print("I'm %s my PID: %i") % (name, os.getpid())
        time.sleep(2)
    print "NO MORE "


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()  # начало программы
```

**В создателе потоков:**

```
def create_proc(self, body):
    p = Process(target=New_Func, args=(body["name"],))
    self.lock.acquire()
    try:
        self.table_proc[body["name"]] = p
    except Exception as inst1:
        print(inst) #обработка исключения
        self.lock.release()
        return False
        pass
    finally:  
        self.lock.release()

    p.daemon = True  
    p.start()  
    return True
```

**В киллере:**

```
def kill(self, body):
    self.lock.acquire()  
    try:
        self.table_proc[body["name"]].terminate()  из таблицы
        #os.kill(self.table_proc[body["name"]].pid, 9)
        #os.kill(self.table_proc[body["name"]].pid, os.SIGTERM)
        #os.killpg(os.getpgid(self.table_proc[body["name"]]), os.SIGTERM)
        #todo УДАЛИТЬ из таблицы задач
    except Exception as inst1:
        print(inst1)
        self.lock.release
        return False
        pass
    finally:
        self.lock.release()  
    return True
```

Comment: На юниксах работаете?

Comment: Да, но нужно решение кросплатформенное. Windows/Linux

Comment: [Зомби уже мертвы](http://askubuntu.com/a/427222/3712), всё что осталось это их статус  в родителе прочитать с помощью wait(). Кстати, смешивать потоки и fork()  (Process) это на неприятности напрашиваться (вызывайте Process в процессе, в котором только один поток—в самом начале [можно так называемый fork server запустить](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)).

Comment: Слышал, что кроссплатформенного решения нету. Только если с потоками работать, а не с процессами.

Comment: Процесс это фактически новая обособленная программа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было **найдено** самостоятельно (с коллегой по работе) :

Проблема заключалась в том что, процесс после команды `terminate()` хоть и завершался но полностью ресурсы объекта не освобождались. 
Надеюсь, что решение окажется кросс-платформенным и будет полезно сообществу.

```
def kill(self, body):
    self.lock.acquire()  # блокировка разделяемого объекта 
    try:
        self.table_proc[body["name"]].terminate()  #остановка процесса
        self.table_proc[body["name"]].join() # ждем освобождение ресурсов ("анти-зомбарин")
        del self.table_proc[body["name"]] # убить процесс из таблицы
    except Exception as inst1:
        print(inst1)
        self.lock.release
        return False
        pass
    finally:
        self.lock.release()  # в любом случае освобождаем объект от блокировки
        pass
    return True
```

Для точной проверки будет сделана фабрика процессов для убивания и создания произвольных задач, с проверкой решения.

UPD: решение проверено, работает корректно.

Comment: к чему вы GIL упомянули? (каждый процесс имеет свой GIL) Где у вас ресурсы не освобождаются? (процесс мёртв (зомби) какие у него ресурсы могут быть по вашему? -- прочтите ссылку, которую я выше привёл -- если не ясно, то отдельный вопрос специально о зомби задайте). Не упоминайте людей по имени, если этого не требуется (велика вероятность, что вы не так слова представите: используйте буквальную цитату, если необходимо, и ссылку).

Comment: Ок, босс!
p.s. что такое зомби знал и читал ДО "Вас".

Comment: Stack Overflow это не сайт для помощи лично вам. [Вопрос/ответы обязаны быть полезны не только вам, но и другим людям с похожей проблемой](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044). Это значит что проблема должна быть ясно сформулирована, чтобы другие люди могли найти вопрос через гугл, а ответ решать не только вашу  сиюмиютную задачу, но и задачи людей, которые из поисковика пришли, привлечённые заголовком и текстом вопроса. Не важно кто нашёл ответ—[явно поощряется свои пары вопрос/ответ публиковать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).